# How to make `git fetch` `git rebase origin/master` work in Magit?

Tags: magit, git

I have a branch that I have been working on. At the same time, master branch was evolving.

I decided to put my local branch changes on top of master new changes. Thus, after pulling changes on master, I usually do the following on my local branch:

```bash
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
```

It works. I tried doing the same in Magit. I pressed `F` and chose "pull". Then, I pressed "r" and chose on question "Rebase my-local-branch onto... " `origin/master`. However, there was an error message:

```bash
fatal: Need to specify how to reconcile divergent branches.
```

What is missing? What should I have done?

Obs.: after reading the error message in Magit, I went do the terminal, executed the two commands mentioned above, and everything went fine.

Comment: Which branch are you on when you execute `git rebase origin/master`?

Comment: "I pressed F and chose \"pull\". Then, I pressed "r" and chose on question "Rebase my-local-branch onto... " origin/master." This description is not quite clearly. Try to press `$` (i.e. `M-x magit-process-buffer`) to see the command magit run and check the difference with you expected.